# Application and User Settings C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This is my setting :

```
[global::System.Configuration.SettingsDescription("email")]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("email@domain.ca")]
public string Login
{
    get {
        return ((string)(this["mylogin"]));
    }
    set {
        this["mylogin"] = value;
    }
}
```

`Properties.Settings.Default.Login` gets `[DefaultSettingValueAttribute]` value for Login.

I don't know how to get `[SettingsDescription]` value ?

Comment: It is an attribute. search how to get a declared attribute from a class/property

Comment: BTW The Value from DefaultSettingsValueAttribute is used to set the default value of the property. You cannot access the value from DefaultSettingsValueAttribute via the property - you never know if it was read from the config file or from the attribute